# Laravel 5.4 Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException: JSON decoding of remote response failed. Error code: 4

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

Error in running php artisan dusk.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

On the screenshot, it's beginning of an error in JSON format. The context of error should be below.

Often case is related to Routes, therefore make sure that routes exist and middlewares disabled, specifically - **EncryptCookies**